Не появляется sln. Как настроить?
Не появляется .sln файл при создании проекта. Как настроить?
При создании проекта через Dotnet new console, в проект не добавляется .sln файл. Из за этого не работает автоматическое дополнение. В базе данных есть такой же вопрос и ответ на него(нужно добавить редактор в настройках, или что то вроде того). Но я не знаю как это сделать.

Создание файла решения

Вы по сути сами ответили на свой вопрос, а именно "при создании проекта". Проект и Решение - это две разные вещи, которые создаются отдельно. Как создать "Решение" и добавить в него проект, сказано комментарием выше.
